# Azure AD openid connect not including token_type in response

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am attempting to convert over from the old Azure AD OpenId Connect to use the new Azure AD v2.0 endpoint as documented here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc

When I attempt to request a token via the v2.0 token endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
I get a response that only includes a 'token_id' field, and not a 'token_type', or any other fields.  The library I am using to parse the response is nimbus.com library for openid and auth2.  The OIDCTokenReponseParser throws an exception because the 'token_type' is missing from the response.

I have looked at the OpenID Connect Protocol specifications, and it says that a request to the token endpoint requires 'token_type', so it seems as though the response from the endpoint is invalid.

Has anyone run into this issue, and if so, how did you deal with it?

**UPDATE 3/2/2018**

My flow works with the old end point.  I redirect the user here:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={id}&redirect_uri={uri}&scope=openid+profile+email&state={state}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%7Bid%7D&redirect_uri=%7Buri%7D&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=%7Bstate%7D)

The user logs in, and they are redirected to my app, and code is provided via a query parameter.

I turn around and make this request:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret={secret}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?code=%7Bcode%7D&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=%7Bsecret%7D)

And I get response that looks like this.

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "ext_expires_in": "0",
    "expires_on": "1520018953",
    "access_token": "{token}",
    "refresh_token": "{token}",
    "id_token": "{token}"
}
```

I try to handle v2.0 version the same way.  I redirect the user to:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={id}&redirect_uri={uri}&scope=openid+profile+email&state={state}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%7Bid%7D&redirect_uri=%7Buri%7D&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=%7Bstate%7D)

And after they sign in, they are redirected back to my app with the 'code' as a query parameter.

I then send this request:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret={secret}&redirect_uri={uri}&client_id={id}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?code=%7Bcode%7D&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=%7Bsecret%7D&redirect_uri=%7Buri%7D&client_id=%7Bid%7D)

But this is the response I get:

```
{
"id_token":"{token}"
}
```

Comment: What is the `response_type` sent to the `/authorize` endpoint, `id_token` or `id_token code`? Please update your question with more details about the grant flow you used, and you could provide the detailed request trace for us to narrow down this issue.

Comment: @BruceChen I have updated my question with more details about the requests I am making

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scopes you've requested can all be satisfied with the contents of the ID Token only. In your Auth Request, try including a scope that would indicate that you need an access token (e.g. https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read), and the response will have the expected `token_type` and `access_token`.

Comment: That worked.  And you are correct, I only need the id token, but the library I am using apparently assumes I need more than just the id token.  I'll let them know.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Great that it works! I'm not entirely sure if OpenID Connect specifies whether or not the Token Response *must* include an access token... I'll look into that on our side as well.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret - according to the [OIDC Spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenResponse) the response **must** include an access token.

Comment: I tend to agree with you on that, and have raised this with our protocol experts. :)